# Overrride TD CSS with TR CSS

Tags: css, overriding, html-table

In my HTML table I have different colors for my rows and columns. But on intersection of a row and column, the TD CSS takes the precedence. But I want to over ride it with TR CSS. How this can be done?

Here is an example from my work
[image]

I want to have gray color like in first row in all the cells/columns.As this is a disabled row.But the column css overrides the row css.

Comment: Can you give us some HTML or CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try overriding the td with a transparent color this particular td.
Something like this :

```
table tr.disabled td{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

if your css declaration for the column td has more precision, then you need to add more precision to this declaration (maybe add a css class or go up in the precision like `html body table tr.disabled td`).